# Why is a Spatial Data Frame obtained from OSM/Nominatim invalid?

Tags: r, openstreetmap, r-sf, tmap, nominatim

I want to get plottable spatial (boundary/polygon) data from OpenStreetMap using the [`nominatim` R package](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/nominatim/).

The `nominatim::osm_search_spatial` request seems to work successfully but the resulting data, despite being found as a "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", is shown as invalid and I am not able to get it to plot with `plot` or `tmap`. It also seems to be missing its CRS.

I am not sure if I am missing a step or two, or if there is indeed something wrong with the data that is retrieved from OSM (seems unlikely, but possible).

**Edit:** There seems to be a problem with the latitudes and longitudes in the data received so this question has been edited with a new reprex. It looks like it might need to be asked on a GIS forum rather than here in R, in fact.

**Deleted previous reprex** showing superfluous steps and results (moved to gist [here](https://gist.github.com/francisbarton/3028d3f73e67091c40647345f0077552)) - this is what Eugene Chong in his first reply was responding to.

Here's my new, more focused, reprex showing the problem (OSM API key hidden). You can see that the polygon @coords leap from the first point at -1,-1 right up to 53,53 for the second point onwards, hence the diagonal line that is plotted.

```r
library(nominatim)
#> Data (c) OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright
#> Nominatim Usage Policy: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy
#> MapQuest Nominatim Terms of Use: http://info.mapquest.com/terms-of-use/
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3
library(tmap)
library(tibble)

# get OSM search results for Ashfield district (UK)
ashfield <- nominatim::osm_search_spatial("Ashfield", limit = 1, key = $my_osm_api_key)
class(ashfield)
#> [1] "list"

# extract SPDF from list
ashfield <- ashfield[[1]]
class(ashfield)
#> [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "sp"

# Convert to an SF object and try again
ashfield_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(ashfield)
class(ashfield_sf)
#> [1] "sf"         "data.frame"

# set CRS (thanks to Eugene Chong)
st_crs(ashfield_sf) <- 4326
tmap::qtm(ashfield_sf)
#> Warning: The shape ashfield_sf is invalid. See sf::st_is_valid
```

[image]

```r
glimpse(ashfield@data)
#> Observations: 1
#> Variables: 15
#> $ place_id     <chr> "186877616"
#> $ licence      <chr> "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://...
#> $ osm_type     <chr> "relation"
#> $ osm_id       <chr> "154043"
#> $ lat          <dbl> 53.08977
#> $ lon          <dbl> -1.251877
#> $ display_name <chr> "Ashfield, Nottinghamshire, East Midlands, England, Un...
#> $ class        <chr> "boundary"
#> $ type         <chr> "administrative"
#> $ importance   <dbl> 0.2116014
#> $ icon         <chr> "http://ip-10-98-176-55.mq-us-east-1.ec2.aolcloud.net/...
#> $ bbox_left    <fct> 53.0080617
#> $ bbox_top     <fct> 53.1714343
#> $ bbox_right   <fct> -1.3445928
#> $ bbox_bottom  <fct> -1.1642542
head(ashfield@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords)
#>           [,1]      [,2]
#> [1,] -1.344593 -1.344409
#> [2,] 53.063537 53.063260
#> [3,] 53.064985 53.063764
#> [4,] 53.065520 53.065521
#> [5,] 53.065553 53.065526
#> [6,] 53.065725 53.065656
ashfield_sf$geometry
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -1.344593 ymin: -1.344593 xmax: 53.17143 ymax: 53.17142
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#> POLYGON ((-1.344593 -1.344409, 53.06354 53.0632...
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Next step: I am going to try a direct download from nominatim rather than via the R package, and see what I get.

Comment: This github issue looks like it might be relevant: https://github.com/openstreetmap/Nominatim/issues/740

Comment: Searching nominatim [manually](https://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?key=KtacQGOTApeFbfDhKaq5cGk8T16V4ioP&format=json&q=ashfield&limit=1) gives valid output, but just the location data not the spatial data (like doing `nominatim::osm_search` rather than `nominatim::osm_search_spatial`)  
  
It's not clear to me how to do a 'spatial' search on the mapquest/nominatim website.

Comment: Ah - just need to add `&polygon=1` on to the search query to the mapquest api - that returns the polygon.

Comment: I've filed this as an issue on nominatim R package: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/nominatim/issues/20

Answer (score 1):

Using `st_make_valid()` from the `lwgeom` package makes the warning go away:

Add WGS84 as the crs.

```
ashfield_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(ashfield)
st_crs(ashfield_sf) <- 4326

sf::st_is_valid(ashfield_sf, reason = TRUE)

[1] "Self-intersection[53.0709899483331 53.0709561246412]"
```

Use `st_make_valid()`

```
library(lwgeom)
ashfield_sf_2 <- st_make_valid(ashfield_sf)
sf::st_is_valid(ashfield_sf_2, reason = TRUE)

[1] "Valid Geometry"
```

As far as the geometry itself, though, it's still just a line extending from Russia to the west coast of Africa, not a polygon of Ashfield as would be expected.

And as far as why the geometry was invalid in the first place, I'm not sure, but the self-intersection error suggests that the polygon crossed over itself at some point (like a bowtie would).  See this post, which has more discussion of valid and invalid geometries: https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2017/03/19/invalid.html

Comment: That's helpful Eugene (hi, again!) - thanks.
I have just noticed something that gives me a big clue as to what is wrong here.

In the data from OSM we have:
```
bbox_left   bbox_top bbox_right bbox_bottom
53.0080617 53.1714343 -1.3445928  -1.1642542
```

This looks kind of OK at first, but of course it's wrong: the `bbox_left` number (in Russia!) should be assigned to `bbox_bottom`, and the `bbox_bottom` number (Africa!) should be the `bbox_left` number.

53.* should be latitudes and -1.* should be longitudes, but latitudes are being presented as longitudes and vice versa.

Comment: Hello again!  Hm, I see.  I'm not sure either of these works, but maybe two solutions. First might be to `st_cast()` the polygon to points, get the coordinates with `st_coordinates()`, `st_as_sf()` with the coordinates flipped, and then `st_cast()` back to polygon. Second could be to `apply()` through the geometry column and flip the first number with the second for every coordinate.